# Haskell - List Error

Tags: list, loops, haskell

I'm trying to iterate a list and square all the number and add them together

```
sumsq  (x:xs) = 
let total = 0
loop length(x:xs) (x:xs) total


loop 0 (x:xs) = return ()
loop n (x:xs)  total = 
do
    let 
        sq = ((x:xs)!!n)^2
        total = total + sq
    loop ((n-1) (x:xs) total)
```

But I'm getting `parse error in loop`. Where am I going wrong?

Also is there a better way to do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all - you miss spaces! It is significant.

Second, you forget `in` from `let ... in`. We could not use `in` in `do`-notation:

```
sumsq  (x:xs) = 
   let total = 0 in
   loop length(x:xs) (x:xs) total
```

Third, you do not use `x` and `xs` form `(x:xs)` :

```
sumsq  xs = 
    let total = 0 in
    loop (length xs) xs total
```

And we unite our `length xs`in one block. It is fourth.

Fifth, we have 3, not 2 arguments for loop:

```
loop 0 xs total  = return total
```

Sixth, (!!) work from 0, but you use it from 1, so `(xs !! (n -1))` is right

Seventh, you don't need to use monad, just recursion. So, get rid from `return` and `do`

Eighth. you have infinite recursive `total = total + smth`

Ninth, we can't use arguments as tuple, so, you final working result is :

```
sumsq  xs = 
    let total = 0 in
    loop (length xs) xs total


loop 0 xs total = total
loop n xs total = loop (n-1) xs total1
    where 
        sq = (xs !! (n -1)) ^2
        total1 = total + sq
```

**UPDATED**

If we are talking about complexity, it is not good - `O(n^2)` as it is mentioned in comments : for each element we seek this element.
We could simplify our loop function and get rid of `n` argument:

```
loop []     total = total
loop (x:xs) total = loop xs total1
    where 
        sq = x ^ 2
        total1 = total + sq
```

and our `sumsq` function we write:

```
sumsq  xs = loop xs 0
```

P.S.
This is an implementation much easier function `sumsq = sum. map (^ 2)`

Comment: I am not sure it is a good idea to make this horribly styled program work. Obviously, the OP has not the slightest idea of pattern matching, and it would be better to make him learn it, so he can "iterate a list" in the idiomatic way.

Comment: Thank s alot but I don't understand the **third** part. I can't I use `(x:xs)`? Besides, what does `x` and `xs` really mean? I know they `x` is the head of the list but what about `xs`?

Comment: @AdegokeA , you can, example `f (x:xs) = x+1:f xs`, but in this case you don't use, so we write it simpler - `xs` (or `x`), doesn't matter, it is a name of argument only

Answer (score 3):

If I understood you correctly, you could simply do this with `map` and `sum`:

```
Prelude> let myFun = sum . map (^2)
Prelude> myFun [1, 2, 3]
14
```

Or with `foldl1` and lambda:

```
Prelude> let myFun' = foldl1 (\s x -> s + x^2)
Prelude> myFun' [1, 2, 3, 4]
30
```

Answer (score 3):

Surely something like this would be the usual approach?

```
sumSquared :: [Integer] -> Integer
sumSquared [] = 0
sumSquared (x:xs) = (x * x) + sumSquared xs
```

Or you could do this even more succinctly with `foldr`, or `sum` and `map` (like @soon's answer)

Comment: Thanks. Is `xs` the rest of the list when you do the recursion?

Comment: Yep: `x` is the head element and `xs` is the tail list.

Answer (score 1):

The `do` must be more indented than the word `loop`.

Apart from that, you don't need `do` (or `return`) at all here, unless you can answer the question which monad this is for?

There are more problems with your code. One of the most severe is this:

You don't seem to know what "pattern matching" is, nor what it is good for. You really want to learn about it, otherwise you can't write any good programs.